# Dynamic sharepoint form which uses Drop down menu to select the form

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, infopath, infopath-2013

I'm trying to create a dynamic form in sharepoint which uses drop down menu to choose the type of form, for example I need to submit a form to a department and each department will have different forms and the user can choose the department on top and the form below should change depending on the selection above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Infopath form to achieve this. Create a rule that switches views based on the value of the drop down menu.

You could refer to the following articles:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-button-for-switching-views-2cddeaf6-3e4a-462a-96bc-33b6e0bde672

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-delete-and-switch-views-pages-in-a-form-89677734-2a77-47fa-8c04-d83fd24f18c2